# How to capture raw keyboard input on Windows

Tags: c, windows, input, io

I have a device that acts like a HID (keyboard). I was able to capture and grab the raw input of the device on Linux. I needed to get exclusive rights to the device so that no other application could receive input from it. I accomplished this using `ioctl` and `EVIOCGRAB`

But it doesn't compile under Windows. I have found that there is a `RegisterRawInputDevices` function but it doesn't seem to provide exclusive rights to the device. What could be used on Windows to achieve the same effect?

Here is my code that works on Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct input_event ev[64];
    int fevdev = -1;
    int result = 0;
    int size = sizeof(struct input_event);
    int rd;
    int value;
    char name[256] = "Unknown";
    char *device = "/dev/input/event16";

    fevdev = open(device, O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fevdev, EVIOCGRAB, 1);

    while (1)
    {
        read(fevdev, ev, size * 64);
        value = ev[0].value;
        printf ("code - %d \n", ev[1].code);
    }

    ioctl(fevdev, EVIOCGRAB, 0);
    close(fevdev);
}
```

Comment: Can you use cygwin?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I guess... how would it work?

Comment: Cygwin allows you to have a Linux-like environment on Windows.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to grab input on Windows, an alternative to ````EVIOCGRAB````

Comment: You can set a keyboard hook using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD_LL as the hook id https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa